# Creating a single dictionary from 3 lists one being a nested list

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a single dictionary from 3 lists one being a nested list.

```
Companies = ['Company A', 'Company B']
features = ['Feature 1', 'Feature 2', 'Feature 3']
values = [['On', 'Off', 'On'], ['Off', 'On', 'Off']]

# This is what i would like the out put to look like, any help would be great 

results = {{'Company A': {'Feature 1' : 'On', 'Feature 2': 'Off', 'Feature 
3': 'On'}, 'Company B': {'Feature 1' : 'Off', 'Feature 2': 'On', 'Feature 
3': 'Off'}}}
```

Comment: What have you tried already?  StackOverflow is not here to write your code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Companies = ['Company A', 'Company B']
features = ['Feature 1', 'Feature 2', 'Feature 3']
values = [['On', 'Off', 'On'], ['Off', 'On', 'Off']]
results = {}

for i in range(len(Companies)):
    results[Companies[i]] = dict(zip(features,values[i]))

print (results)
```

Output:

{'Company A': {'Feature 3': 'On', 'Feature 2': 'Off', 'Feature 1': 'On'}, 'Company B': {'Feature 3': 'Off', 'Feature 2': 'On', 'Feature 1': 'Off'}}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
results = {comp: {feat: v for feat,v in zip(features,val)} for comp,val in zip(Companies,values)}
```

Output:

```
{'Company A': {'Feature 1': 'On', 'Feature 2': 'Off', 'Feature 3': 'On'}, 'Company B': {'Feature 1': 'Off', 'Feature 2': 'On', 'Feature 3': 'Off'}}
```